# Updating multiple versions of JPA entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

Background-> I have an employee table that is represented by many JPA entities in the code - EmployeeBasic and EmployeeDetails.
Each of these JPA entities have different levels of details - the basic entity has only the employee name and id. The detailed entity has other details such as startdate, department etc, in addition to the name and id.

Now coming to the issue -> I have a place in the code which updates the name of the entity using the EmployeeBasic entity. In another part of the code, the EmployeeDetails entity is being used. But, it is not synched with the updated name automatically. Is there a way to handle it in JPA so that both versions of the entity are in sync?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a behavior in JPA/Hibernate.

Synching automatically is not possible, because Hibernate is not aware of object modifications until flush-time. So when you change `EmployeeBasic`'s name, Hibernate will not notice it before dirty-check.

However, I think that it would not be a good design to make something like this anyway. The best approach is to unify all of your different entities mapped to the same table (rows) into one entity, so that persistence context is never in an inconsistent state regarding to DB and other entities.

Answer (score 0):

JPA allows caching at different layers, so that even if all processes were using the same Employee entity, it would require careful design to make sure that all processes were synched with the updated name automatically.  The reason for this is that an EntityManager is meant to be treated transactionally; reading from it will give you managed instance of entities that then are isolated from changes made in other EntityManagers.  The data in the database is only a concern when it comes time to write.  This allows you to work on them without worrying about data changing out from under you, and manage any problems yourself (some form of optimistic locking is recommended).

Your case is also complicated by the fact that although EmployeeBasic and EmployeeDetails may reuse the same database table, JPA allows for a shared cache as well.  So making changes to EmployeeBasic will update its cache and shared cache, but the EmployeeDetails cache will be stale.  This is similar to having multiple persistence units accessing the same tables.

The way this is handled is that the application is responsible and can control when they want to refresh their entities, the level of caching and invalidation of the caches.   JPA allows turning off the shared cache (using isolated caches), so that when you read from a new EntityManager, it will always go to the database for the data, and see changes in any of the entities.  It also has refresh api (and most providers have refresh hints) that allow you to force a query to the database when you know something might need to be checked, though care must be taken as it wipes out changes.

EclipseLink (I'm not familiar with Hibernate) has cache invalidation options and cache coordination that could be used together with events, so that you can take advantage of shared caches; you could use update events to trigger all Employee** caches related to that updated to become invalidated.